# How to configure Firewall/NAT properly

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am trying to set up KVM virtual machine by following this tutorial:
https://sandilands.info/sgordon/linux-servers-as-kvm-virtual-machines

I cant get Firewall/NAT configured properly. Ip 192.168.1.100 should be forwarded to 192.168.122.100 if I understand the tutorial correctly. But I get "Connection refused" error. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

*side note:*

- 192.168.1.10 is the same as 192.168.1.2 in tutorial and
- 192.168.1.100 is the same as 192.168.1.10 in tutorial

**my interface configuration (ifconfig output):**

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/xx Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:xxxxxx errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:yyyyyy errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:569834067 (569.8 MB)  TX bytes:33729447 (33.7 MB)

enp1s0:0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

**iptable rules I applied:**

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.100 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.100
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.100 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.100
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.122.100 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.122.100 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

**Testing the connection. Connection is refused.**

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.100 80
Trying 192.168.1.100...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Comment: Are you testing the connection on the same host machine (same machine configured with iptables rules)?

Comment: Yes, this is all on the same host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting from the same machine, the `DNAT` rule in `PREROUTING` chain is not executed. It will affect traffic passing through host machine when acting as a router. You need to add `DNAT` rule in `OUTPUT` chain.

You can try to add a rule like the following and redo the test:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.100 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.100
```

Comment: You sir just saved my day. Upvote, marked as correct answer!